# wordpress homepage not main url

Tags: wordpress, url

We are currently developing our own theme for Wordpress. Now we set up the index.php and added the first page which is functioning as the Homepage. (we have installed WP on a subdirectory)

We setup Wordpress that the Homepage is set to that new added page. But now this new page is only accessable by www.domain.com/wp/home instead of www.domain.com/wp

How can we set up WP that it will show the new added page at the Homepage?

Answer (score 3):

By default WordPress shows your most recent posts on the front page. In order to change that you need to set the Wordpress front page to be a static page.

1. Go to **Administration Menu > Settings > Reading** panel.
2. Set 'Front page displays:' to 'a static page' and choose the page you already created for 'Front page:'.
3. Save changes.

> For More Information:
>
> - [Creating a Static Front Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)
> - [Wordpress Settings Reading Screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_SubPanel)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set it up in Themes menu. You will find an option there,what do you want to show on your start page, blog, or a page. Specify your page there.